# VB.net logic to catch errors in functions

Tags: vb.net, function, error-handling

I'm not a pro and I learn by myself a few of coding rules.
I started with `vba` and now I'm approaching to `vb.net` but my knowledge is very poor.

I wrote this function to extract a column from a recordset (query on DB) and put it into an Hashset of string.

Trying to handle errors on wrong number of column, I used these criteria:

1) declare "`mErr`" as `boolean` in code that calls the function;

2) send "`mErr`" `byRef` to the function;

3) when error occur: change `mErr` to true and insert into `mHash` an empty string.

```
Public Function RSCol(ByVal mRS As Object, ByVal mCol As Byte, ByRef mErr As Boolean)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mHash As New HashSet(Of String)
    If mRS.GetUpperBound(0) < mCol Then
        mErr = True
        mHash.Add("")
        Return mHash
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 0 To mRS.GetUpperBound(1)
        mHash.Add(mRS(mCol, i))
    Next
    Return mHash
End Function
```

It seems to work but I think isn't a good coding and I would like to improve my coding skill.

Every suggest is appreciated.

Comment: Well ideally to do error management you should work with `try/catch/finally`statements and throw exceptions from user-defined functions.

Comment: @Bartdude Thanks, but I didn't understand how to tell to the calling code that function fails with a more elegant/functionally code

Comment: I don't know how to tell it better than my previous remark, the elegant way is to throw an  exception...

Comment: Put `Options Strict On` at the top of your code file or set it in your projects settings.  This will help you to find and overcome coding errors.  In this case, your function does not specify a return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code :

> `Exit Function` is unreachable since the `Return` statement above the
>   `Exit Function` function will transfer the control out to the
>   function.
>
> More over a function should return a value otherwise you will get a
>   warning. in such cases you can use `Sub`.

You code can be

```
 Public Function RSCol(ByVal mRS As Object, ByVal mCol As Byte, ByRef mErr As Boolean) As HashSet(Of String)
        Dim loopCounter As Long
        Dim mHash As New HashSet(Of String)
        Try
            If mRS.GetUpperBound(0) < mCol Then
                Throw New Exception("")
            End If
            For loopCounter = 0 To mRS.GetUpperBound(1)
                mHash.Add(mRS(mCol, loopCounter))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            mHash.Add(ex.ToString())
        End Try
        Return mHash
    End Function
```

You can refer Try..Catch mechanism in detail [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)
For more about [Exceptions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_exception_handling.htm)

Since i notice that your naming conventions are so poor i suggest you to go through this [article by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, your review makes me understand the logic of try/catch and how the exceptions works. Only a few questions: in the calling code, to understand that function fails, I need to examine the returned string? Would be it correct inserting of an error message into the hashset, so to check if it contains the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should throw and handle Exceptions. Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **exceptions** to control error on functions. When you detect something is going wrong within your function, you throw it:

```
if ( something ) then 'check if something bad happened
  Throw New Exception("X has occurred")
end if
```

Then, when this function which throw this exception, you should catch it like:

```
try
    ' Code with the call to the function which throws the exception
catch excp as Exception
    'Your control code for this situation, as example just show it
    MessageBox.show(excp.Message)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question let me make clear about two things:

1. Error
2. Exception

> **Exceptions** are those which can be handled at the run time whereas
>   **errors** cannot be handled.

It is always a good practice to handle exception/errors effectively.

Here comes **Try-Catch-Throw**  for our rescue.

Basic Syntax :

```
Try
    ' Do something in here that
    ' might raise an error.
  Catch
    ' Handle exceptions that occur within
    ' the Try block, here.
  Finally
    ' Perform cleanup code in here.
  End Try
```

**Try**: A Try block identifies a block of code for which particular exceptions will be activated. It's followed by one or more Catch blocks.

**Catch**: A program catches an exception with an exception handler at the place in a program where you want to handle the problem. The Catch keyword indicates the catching of an exception.

**Finally**: The Finally block is used to execute a given set of statements, whether an exception is thrown or not thrown. For example, if you open a file, it must be closed whether an exception is raised or not.

**Throw**: A program throws an exception when a problem shows up. This is done using a Throw keyword.

If you are not getting any exception in program also it is recommended to use the try catch blocks